# Can you help me finding the best method to add long paragraphs in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know  about html plugins which can be used to add pages of long paragraphs

I also know about flutter codes which can be used to add long paras of texts

But I am not satisfied with both methods..

I am creating a lesson app and want to insert tons of texts and images in a beautifully way...

Can you suggest me any way [better way] to add long texts with   keeping eye on the size of the app

I have added screenshots for reference

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [Zefyr](https://zefyr-editor.gitbook.io/docs/). It's a WYSIWYG that can [embed images](https://zefyr-editor.gitbook.io/docs/images), [display lists](https://zefyr-editor.gitbook.io/docs/concepts/attributes) and even has collaborative editing capabilities. If you only wanted it for presentation you could make it view only by changing the mode to `ZefyrMode.view` on the `ZefyrEditor` constructor.

Edit:
Another more lightweight solution is to use [`flutter_markdown`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown). It also supports images, lists and so on and doesn't require the special delta format that Zefyr does when storing your strings of text.

Comment: I already know about them.I used zefyr and markdown in a math formula app & lesson app resepctively. But we can not make stylish looking .[good UI] text contents using them.

Comment: Sorry @ramanraman I'm not sure what you mean by using json. If it's just that the style isn't matching what you have in mind, `flutter_markdown` has a [stylesheet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/blob/master/lib/src/style_sheet.dart) that you can customize. For example, I use the `largeFromTheme` constructor to have larger fonts as well as changing the default headings to a different fontstyle than the `p` fontstyle.